# How to turn off SSL check on Chrome and Firefox for localhost

Tags: ssl, https, webrtc

I'm making a web app that uses `WebRTC` but it requires `https`. Is there any way to turn off SSL check on Chrome and Firefox for **localhost only** or is there any way to make use of `WebRTC` without `https`? Thanks.

Comment: What's the error message in the console on Chrome?

Comment: I just check, it works fine on Chrome but Firefox doesn't allow the page to use the camera.

Comment: @TriNguyen what errors do you get in the Firefox console? Both Chrome and Firefox treat `localhost` as a secure context.

Comment: I'm following this https://github.com/mdn/samples-server/tree/master/s/webrtc-capturestill and Firefox gives `navigator.mozGetUserMedia has been replaced by navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`

Comment: OK. Your issue is not HTTPS related. Both Chrome and Firefox treat localhost as a secure context, so localhost should have access to secure context only features like webcam, geolocation, and WebRTC. According to firefox's error, it just wants you to use a different API.

Comment: You might check out [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) for generating a self-signed certificate and how to add that cert to your trusted sources list (depending on your OS). Once you've done this, you can start your server with that new cert and then you won't need browser overrides

Comment: Hi Brady, thank you for the recommendation. I indeed have been using mkcert for a year. Works flawlessly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @vcsjones said

> Both Chrome and Firefox treat localhost as a secure context, so localhost should have access to secure context only features like webcam, geolocation, and WebRTC.

It is correct. However, Firefox changed (since Firefox 42) `mozSrcObject` to `srcObject`. I changed it to that and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

Chrome has chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost which will ignore certificate errors on localhost. This makes development much easier.

Answer (score 5):

The way to continue and access the server will be by clicking on an empty location at the background with the browser's error page and type:
thisisunsafe

Comment: what? this actually worked!! hahahahaha

Answer (score 3):

Since `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` feature is removed from Chrome 88 disable security settings completely helped me to send requests from localhost to server.

[Google Security Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6J1D.png)

Comment: that sounds like a bad idea. http://localhost should be treated like a secure origin though, so you might rather want to use http?

Comment: Haha yes this sounds pretty scary 

Comment: @PhilippHancke Unfortunately, http won't work if you need to send requests to https

Comment: This removal was apparently not intended, should be back after https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2595514